# If condition as one liner

Tags: shell-script

How do I get an one liner for this condition?

```
if [ -f ~/.ssh/config ]
then
    echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x94 Config file existing"
fi
```

My attempt:

```
if [ ! -f ~/.ssh/config ] || echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x94 Config file existing"
```

Comment: so this is correct? `if [ ! -f ~/.ssh/config ] || echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x94 Config file existing"` I have to check for the opposite, right?

Comment: You don't want the `if` keyword. Normally you use `&&` to connect the 2 commands and do not reverse the condition but using || with a reversed condition is valid. so `[ -f ~/.ssh/config ] && echo ...`

Comment: Don't forget that the first word after `if` is a *command* (`if command; then A; else B; fi`) -- that means that `[` and `[[` are *commands*.

Comment: Please don't edit a question to *include* its answer — especially not a wrong answer. If your "Update" is not meant to be a proposed answer, explain what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most readable way (IMHO) is to use the `test` utility explicitly:

```
test -f ~/.ssh/config && echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x94 Config file existing"
```

Comment: Yep, or one could just use square brackets. Same thing.

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
if [ -f ~/.ssh/config ]; then echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x94 Config file existing"; fi
```

or

```
[ ! -f ~/.ssh/config ] || echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x94 Config file existing"
```

or

```
[ -f ~/.ssh/config ] && echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x94 Config file existing"
```

and the `else` has to come last

```
[ -f ~/.ssh/config ] && echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x94 Config file existing" || echo -e "\xE2\x9E\x97 No config file"
```